# how to show items in a flowlayout manner in datalist/repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater, datalist

I have a list of suppose 10 videos whose thumbnail i want to show in a data control

Like this:

Vid1    Vid2    Vid3     Vid4

Vid5   Vid6    Vid7     Vid8

Vid9   Vid10

and so on

and also which control i should use like Repeater or DataList